# Online backup blocking truncate table

Tags: db2

It´s documented that in DB2 the TRUNCATE statement is not compatible with online backup because it gets a Z lock on the table and prevents an online backup from running concurrently.
The lock wait happens when a truncate tries to get a shared lock on an internal online backup object.

Since this is by design in the product I will have to go for workarounds, so this thread is not about a solution, but why they can´t work together. I didn´t find a reasonable explanation why there is such limitation in db2.

Any insights?

Thanks,
Luciano Moreira

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0501melnyk/

> When a table holds a Z lock, no concurrent application can read or
>   update data in that table.

So now we know that a Z lock is and exclusive access to a table denying read and write access to the table.

from  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053474.html

> **Exclusive Access:** No other session can have a cursor open on the table, or a lock held on the table (SQLSTATE 25001).

from https://sites.google.com/site/umeshdanderdbms/difference-between-truncate-and-delete

> 1. Delete is logging operation, where as Truncate is makes the table empty on container level.
>      (Logging operation – DML operation are logged into logs (redo log in oracle, transaction log in DB2 etc). It is stored in logs for commit or rollback operation.)

This is the most interesting part. Truncate just 'forgets' the content of the table whereas deletes removes line by line processing all triggers, bells, and whistles. Therefore when you truncate all reading cursors will get invalid. To prevent stupid stuff like that you can only completely empty a table when nobody tries to access it. Online backup obviously needs to read the table. Therefore it is not possible to have both accessing the same table at the same time.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the information. I did a quickly review of the article and it does not point in the direction I want. The truncate table successfully acquires a Z lock in the table but gets blocked by an "internal online backup" lock. Do Z locks always try to get that lock? The reason for this question is try to explore some of the details of why DB2 works this way.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the detail regarding Z locks. I couldn´t agree more that when a backup tries to read an object that is in the middle of a truncate operation it should be blocked. 
What I still don´t agree is with the DBMS implementation of blocking the truncate table until the end of the backup, SQL Server for instance allows both operations to occur. In our case I got a 15 TB database and every 12 hours a truncate table is issued against a table with 500.000 rows, which depending on the schedule it will be blocked for hours before the truncate completes, generating a lock chain.

Comment: If the table has 500 rows, may be a standard delete will do. Not sure about the locking though. BTW, it would have helped, if you would have put that example in the question right away. Sometimes, people come up with creative ideas for real world problems.  .... When I think about it, why do you put 500.000 rows into a table to throw them away after 12 hours?